# Unable to use SSIS package for importing data to Azure Data Warehouse using Data Factory

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We are trying to copy the data from on-premise system to Azure Data Warehouse. We want to use SSIS package for copy data from on premise to cloud. Azure Data Factory v1 does not support SSIS package and Azure Data factory v2 supports SSIS packages but it does not supported by Data Warehouse.

So My Question is, How to import data from On-premise database to Azure Data Warehouse using Azure Data Factory SSIS package?

Thanks in Advance,
Vinir Shah

[image: Ref Diagram]

Comment: Hi Vinir Shah, I'm afrait we can't do that. Only the  self-host integration runtime can help us connect to on-premise data source. I tested and always get the error. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can't copy the data from on-premise system to Azure Data Warehouse with SSIS package running in Data Factory.

To copy the data from on-premise system to Azure Data Warehouse, we could do with two ways:

1. Run the SSIS package local: [Load data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-sql-data-warehouse?view=sql-server-ver15#option-1---use-the-sql-dw-upload-task).
2. Using Copy activity to copy the data from on-premise system to Azure
   Data Warehouse with self-host integration runtime.

Data Factory SSIS-integration runtime can't get data from the on-premise SQL server. I tested run the package in Data Factory and always get the error bellow:

```
Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ".
```

As we know about Data Factory, only the [self-host integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) can help us connect to on-premise data source.

Hope this helps.